# SQL Server: creating linked server to Access DB fails with Error 7403

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, driver

On SQL Srver 2012R2 Express I created a linked server to Access 2010 32bit DB to IMPORT data from Access to SQL-server.

But when I run a query

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MSAccessConnect, 'SELECT * FROM [myAccesstable]')
```

I get error 7403: 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider not registered.

Same with 'Microsoft. Jet.OLEDB.4.0' btw.

What I found out so far is that I have NO such driver for 64 bit Version installed, but only the 32 bit version, as Access is 32 bit.

So how can I install the 64 bit verison of that driver?

Where can I find the driver (is this "AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe" ??)?

And am I sure, that the 32bit driver is not deleted or overwritten?

I may not "harm" my Office 2010 32bit installation, as there are to many things depending on 32 bit!!

The thing, which makes me wonder is, when using the import wizzard in SSMS it works, but when trying it with a linked server it fails.
So somehow in the wizzard it works without the correct driver, I guess.

Thanks your help
Michael

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Your link points to the "AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe", which I already found. Does your reply mean, that my concerns about existing 32bit driver are unfounded?